# How to get list of all routes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, command-line, router

Is it possible to get the list of all routes in a Magento 2 environment? I am looking some command-line tool, if there is any?

Note: I had a `bin/rails routes` command to list all the routes in rails framework, and I am looking something similar to this.

Comment: I wrote a similar tool a long time ago. The code is already deleted, but I can share the basic steps for this tool. Are you interested?

Comment: My good beloved rails...

Comment: Hi @AndreyKonosov, after long time, yes I am interested :).

Comment: It is really disappointing there is not any way to list all the routes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [n98](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun):

> n98-magerun.phar config:dump frontend/routers

Comment: https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/issues/253

Comment: This is for magento 1 I think. It does not work with n98-magerun2.

Comment: is there any soution for magento2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [n98-magerun2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2):

> n98-magerun2.phar route:list

Example output:

```
+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Area      | Frontname                   | Module                              | Route                                                             |
+-----------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| frontend  | stores                      | Magento_Store                       | stores/store/redirect                                             |
| frontend  | stores                      | Magento_Store                       | stores/store/switchrequest                                        |
| frontend  | stores                      | Magento_Store                       | stores/store/switch                                               |
| frontend  | stores                      | Magento_Store                       | stores/store/switchaction/cookiemanager                           |
| frontend  | directory                   | Magento_Directory                   | directory/currency/switch
...
```